# WKWebView Blank on Catalina

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

In my Mac OSX app Am loading HTML from local file system (file:// URL) but on OSX Catalina it show a blank white screen, it works in fine in previous Mac versions.

It works fine in Debug or Release mode so prob a setting when it get signed for AppStore submissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also had local file issues in the original 10.15 build release, I've "heard" it is fixed in build `19A603` (released yesterday 10-21-2019), but personally have not verified that...

Note: Other Xcode devs have also reported this issue on beta and production versions (i.e. not an Xamarin related issue)

Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120248